# Writing to a text file, RTL strings are corrupted?

Tags: vba, vb6, right-to-left

I'm trying to write an array of strings/numbers to a text file from VBA. It works well but when there are some RTL strings (Hebrew) the proper order of the strings in the text file seems reversed/corrupted.

Not sure why but It seems to work properly when only one RTL string is involved in the process

I'm using the VBA Print command and a Public Function (Padleft) (Code below)

```
        fff(14) = PadLeft("RTL string1", 15, " ")
        fff(15) = PadLeft(" ", 1, " ")
        fff(16) = PadLeft("RTL string2", 15, " ")

         For lCtr = 14 To 16
            If lCtr < lFieldCount Then                
         Print #iFileNum, fff(lCtr) ;


         Public Function PadLeft(text As Variant, totalLength As Integer, 
         padCharacter As String) As String
         PadLeft = String(totalLength - Len(CStr(text)), padCharacter) & 
         CStr(text)
         End Function
```

Comment: By reversed order, do you mean that the printed output looks like `a b c F E D` ? (here, **a b c** are strings in English, and **D E F** - strings in Hebrew)

Comment: No. If ABC is the 1st Hebrew string and DEF the 2nd Hebrew string, I get DEFABC instead of ABCDEF

Comment: probably I don't understand you correctly, when you print ‭א-ב-ג‬ and after that ‭ד-ה-ו‬ (in RTL), you get אבגדהו from right to left, don't you?

Comment: You are right but the printing logic in VBA is LTR so that I expect from the left אבג then דהו. Moreover, the Hebrew strings are misplaced in the text file (they appear at the end of the record instead of in the middle as instructed by the procedure)

Comment: there is no "LTR printing logic" in VBA. If Hebrew appears in the end instead of in the middle of a text line, this is most likely "on the right", again because this is the way the text line is displayed. To avoid ambiguity, please post a screenshot of the relevant fragment of text.

Comment: When I switch to an RTL view in Notepas++ it shows correctly so it looks as I am doing OK, although I don't completely understand the mechanism

Comment: I agree with @AlexCohn, some screenshots of examples would help a lot

Comment: *When I switch to an RTL view in Notepas++* so you want your output to have RTL order even when the text field (of editor, or browser) dictates LTR order?